# Moving Tensors to the GPU in Pytorch (when using Image Folder)

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I am trying to move my tensors to the GPU after loading them in by using ImageFolder. Below is the relevant code:

```
    train_transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomRotation(10),      # rotate +/- 10 degrees
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),  # reverse 50% of images
        transforms.Resize(224),             # resize shortest side to 224 pixels
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),         # crop longest side to 224 pixels at center
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                             [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])

    train_data = datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(root, 'train'), transform=train_transform)
```

This creates tuples of tensors, but when I then try to iterate through the train_data and move the tensors to the GPU with .cuda(), I get an error because tuples are immutable.

Any ideas to help out? Thank you!!

Comment: Please provide the code where you try to move the tuple to gpu. Anyway, you can do that: im,label = tuple[0].cuda(), tuple[1].cuda()

Comment: it's not the ImageFolder that's causing issue, issue is somewhere else IMO; Please post the whole traceback; How are you iterating etc?